# Are there situations where in vivo results work better than in vitro results would have shown?

Tags: experimental-design

Basically, if I have poor in vitro cell line results but decided to test them in vivo in a mouse anyway what are the possibilities of having better results in the in vivo live mouse model that I would have never known otherwise from the in vitro results?

Links are appreciated

Comment: This is a very broad topic and massively depends on the specifics of your hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Differences between*** **in vitro** ***and*** **in vivo** ***results are (unfortunately) very common!***

Somehow, all failed **clinical trials** (and many **preclinical trials**) are large-scale examples of the discrepancy between promising *in vitro* and actual *in vivo* results - which also highlights the fact that even from one *in vivo* system (e.g. mice) to the other (e.g. humans), there can be significant and unpredictable biological differences. It is the opposite of your case, in which you expect an improvement when moving to live animals, but it is also more common.

By essence, your *in vitro* culture will be unable to recapitulate key processes like:

- **Signals provided by the natural extracellular matrix**. Your cells are probably grown on polystyrene, but that substrate is far from the complexity of the natural molecules that surround cells *in vivo*: stiffness, immobilized signaling molecules...
- **Information provided by other cell types**. Organs are formed of many dynamic subpopulations (stem cells, immune cells etc), some unknown, that interact and control cell behavior at the tissue scale.
- **Fluctuating information** like biological cycles and behaviors (circadian rythm, sleep, food intake...)
- Many others like for instance immune processes, (de)activation of small molecules by enzymes in unrelated organs (liver) or plasma...

All these factors can change your result in unpredictable ways, making them either better or worse. But, and that is important, **more often than not, complex biological systems tend to make things worse**, as they introduce extra noise, buffering effects etc. so more often than not, things will not be as good in a real animal as in a Petri dish. It can get better, sure, but it is extremely unlikely!

That is one of the main reasons why people do *in vitro* work first: it is faster, cheaper and more ethical, and failure *in vitro* is usually a good predictor of downstream failure *in vivo*.

Please, don't cherry-pick an answer that tells you otherwise! It's easier and more comforting to think that everything is going to work if you just move to animals, yes, but you will most likely waste time, money and animal lives for identical results. My (unsolicited) advice is to **build a better *in vitro* model**, that will reduce the possible differences between cell results and animal models: can you mimic a biologically relevant environment by adding a protein/sugar matrix to your cells? Can you find primary cells that will behave more naturally than immortalized cell lines? Can you make mixed cell cultures to improve the adequation of your model with reality? If you do all this, then your results should be much more reliable and you will have a better idea of what to expect *in vivo*.